# Making my project suitable for all iPhone sizes

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

I created a project with a storyBoard and when designing I used the 'view as iPhone11 PRO'. Now when I run the simulator on iPhone 11 MAX I get a hugh white bar on the right side. Ofcouse because the MAX has a bigger screen. Now I tried to set constraints, I tried a lot of different options by using tutorials etc (really a lot). But I just can't seem to get it working on my project.

The problem at the moment, I set all UIImage height and width and added missing constraints by using 'add missing constrains'. The only thing is, it doesn't do anything. I just expected that all images would be a little bit bigger so I'm having the same layout as on the 11 PRO.

ON THE LEFT THE iPHONE 11 PRO - ON THE RIGHT THE iPHONE 11 MAX

[image: 11 PRO]
[image: 11 MAX]

So, I guess the constraints are good but my images don't get bigger when running on a 11 MAX. What would be the best practise for this? (All my images are @x1 @x2 @x1)

Comment: You need to avoid thinking in terms of explicit frame sizes. iOS devices have different screen resolutions, and different aspect ratios. This is a good resource: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions - Your layout can be done with stack views, but the first question is: do you want that ***general layout***? Or, do you want that layout ***keeping aspect ratios***? Compare the images here: https://imgur.com/a/Ecs6s8t

Comment: @DonMag Thanks, the APP will be available only on iPhones (no iPads and no landscape mode). I designed the whole APP with the iPhone 11 PRO view, and I need that exact layout on other iPhone devices as well. So the iPhone 11 MAX has a bigger screen, when I run it I have a big blank white space on the right. So I guess I need to create something that makes the 'tiles' bigger so it will fill up the blank spaces on bigger iPhones to keep the same design I have on the 11 PRO..? This is day 5 I'm trying and I'm really tired and upset of it and out of options :( Can I do this with aspect ratios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"This is day 5 I'm trying..."* - you should have spent those 5 days reading the docs and working through tutorials on auto-layout. As you have quickly found out, there is much more to it than positioning elements on a single sized screen and expecting it to look the same everywhere.

You are thinking that you need to *make the "tiles" bigger for the larger screen*, but what happens when a user runs your app on a ***smaller*** screen?

If you haven't learned about `UIStackView` yet, this may be hard to follow, but it is probably the way you want to go.

The "top" level of your layout has two equal-height sections. So...

We start with a Vertical stack view with **Distribution: Fill Equally**.

- the top half has two equal width sections, so we embed a Horizontal stack view, also with ***Fill Equally**
- the right-half of that section has another two equal-height elements, so we embed a Vertical stack view, also with ***Fill Equally**
- the bottom half has two two equal-height elements, so we embed a Vertical stack view, ***Fill Equally**
- the bottom half of *that* section has two equal width sections, so we embed a Horizontal stack view, ***Fill Equally**

All stack views have ***Spacing: 8***

Now, to get it to fit on various screen sizes - ***while keeping the aspect ratios*** - we'll look at the overall size: Width is 360, and Height is 728 (we need to count the 8-pt spacing). So...

- We'll give the outer-most stack view an Aspect Ratio of `360:728`
- We want to keep everything centered, so give the stack view CenterX and CenterY constraints.
- An iPhone 11 Pro has a width of 375-pts, so to get your exact dimensions we need Leading and Trailing constraints (always to the safe-area) of `7.5`
- The Aspect Ratio constraint will handle the Height

We'll need to make a couple adjustments, and add a few more constraints, to handle other screen sizes...

That layout will "size up" to fit an 11 and an 11 Pro Max fine. However, on an iPhone 8 or 7 or SE, it will be too tall to fit the screen. To handle that, we can...

- change the Leading and Trailing constraints to `>= 7.5` (allowing the stack view to leave a little more space on the sides)
- add Leading and Trailing constraints of **Equal to Zero** with `Priority: 750` (Default High). That tells auto-layout to *try* to pull the sides to the edges
- add Top and Bottom constraints of `>= 0` to prevent it from extending above/below the screen
- add Top and Bottom constraints of **Equal to Zero** with `Priority: 750` (Default High). That tells auto-layout to *try* to pull the top and bottom to the edges

Here's how it looks in Storyboard:

[image]

Note that the image views have ***NO Constraints***, and all stack views are set to **Distribution: Fill Equally** with **Spacing: 8**

Here's how that looks on various devices (very big image - click to see detail):

[image]

Because we cannot draw on "partial pixels" and some devices have 2 pixels-per-point and other devices have 3 pixels-per-point (we don't need to worry about @1x screens anymore) the actual sizes will not be ***exact*** - but they'll be close enough that you'd have to magnify and compare to see the differences.

Here is the source to a Storyboard with that layout so you can inspect it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17156" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="bdh-XY-7ei">
    <device id="retina5_9" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17125"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Schurk Images View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="Zle-Gp-apY">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="bdh-XY-7ei" customClass="SchurkImagesViewController" customModule="DelMe" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Dyb-Gm-pEf">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="812"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Tyg-ff-xjO">
                                <rect key="frame" x="7.6666666666666572" y="47" width="360" height="728"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JqK-ZW-H50">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="360" height="360"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="AtH-1N-5xc">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="176" height="360"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qMO-ld-jJw">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="184" y="0.0" width="176" height="360"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Yhc-Ph-1ck">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="176" height="176"/>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    </imageView>
                                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="nhS-Od-9jO">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="184" width="176" height="176"/>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    </imageView>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="WrS-eH-b3H">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="368" width="360" height="360"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="won-nT-d54">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="360" height="176"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="iS7-mQ-dnf">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="184" width="360" height="176"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xcJ-dz-KeY">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="176" height="176"/>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    </imageView>
                                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0FQ-rZ-x81">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="184" y="0.0" width="176" height="176"/>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    </imageView>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Tyg-ff-xjO" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="360:728" id="SdN-id-c4g"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="Q0H-gV-XLg"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="Tyg-ff-xjO" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Q0H-gV-XLg" secondAttribute="top" priority="750" id="2Ih-jC-mAG"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Tyg-ff-xjO" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="Q0H-gV-XLg" secondAttribute="centerY" id="EnC-xv-6e3"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Tyg-ff-xjO" firstAttribute="top" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="Q0H-gV-XLg" secondAttribute="top" id="KBQ-9p-3NJ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Q0H-gV-XLg" firstAttribute="trailing" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="Tyg-ff-xjO" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="7.5" id="KP5-ws-DRX"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Tyg-ff-xjO" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Q0H-gV-XLg" secondAttribute="leading" priority="750" id="LSW-Dg-4V8"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Q0H-gV-XLg" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Tyg-ff-xjO" secondAttribute="bottom" priority="750" id="N6T-iS-PU1"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Q0H-gV-XLg" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Tyg-ff-xjO" secondAttribute="trailing" priority="750" id="V1E-M5-o7w"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Q0H-gV-XLg" firstAttribute="bottom" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="Tyg-ff-xjO" secondAttribute="bottom" id="gVs-hN-gNr"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Tyg-ff-xjO" firstAttribute="leading" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="Q0H-gV-XLg" secondAttribute="leading" constant="7.5" id="gih-7i-tg8"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Tyg-ff-xjO" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Q0H-gV-XLg" secondAttribute="centerX" id="knQ-zw-EAq"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="ddD-Pk-Baz" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-407" y="1534"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: Thank you! Good explanation, took me some time to get it right! Learned a lot of this!

Answer (score 0):

Each `UIImage` will not change size dynamically with different screen sizes because you set width and height constraints to constants.

I'd suggest removing the constraints on each `UIImage` and instead add them to a `UIStackView`. Add constraints to pin the edges of the UIStackView to the view's `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. The UIStackView will handle resizing your UIImage's based on it's `alignment` and `distribution` properties.

Documentation on UIStackView: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview

Comment: Hey ryanavocado, thanks for your reply. I removed all constraints on the UIButtons (Thought they were UIImages but they are UIButtons instead) Anyway, I pinned the edges of UIStackView to the Safe Area but nothing happends. And I lost my Scrolling options ![Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJL4R.png) . I then tried to pin all edges for each UIButton to the StackView which returns that all UIButtons are centered. It's better than the big white bar but still my images aren't getting any bigger. Do you have any idea's???